# chapter heading appearing in appendix

Tags: fancyhdr

I am using `\fancyhdr` package for the headings and report as a document class
samplecode is given below

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report} 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\chaptername
\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\slshape \leftmark}
\rhead{\thepage}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\input{chap_01}
\input{chap_02}
\input{chap_03}

\begin{appendices}

\input{Appendix_01}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Now everything seems to be working but on the appendix page i get:
[image]

where as instead of chapter i would like 'Appendix A. Parameter Definition'.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply put the line

```
\renewcommand\chaptername{Appendix}
```

just after the line

```
\begin{appendices}
```

[image]

Sample document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\chaptername
\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\slshape \leftmark}
\rhead{\thepage}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{appendices}

\renewcommand\chaptername{Appendix}

\chapter{Parameter Definition}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{35}
some text
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: but shouldn't that be part of the `appendices` routine?

Comment: @barbarabeeton If the OP didn't change the meaning of `\chaptermark` this would have been automatic.

Comment: aha!  i spaced through that.  thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 8):

LaTeX already has a method for changing between `\chaptername` and `\appendixname`; the command `\@chapapp` usually expands to `\chaptername` but is redefined to mean `\appendixname` after `\appendix`.

I have removed from your example something that's not needed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just for the example

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\makeatletter % necessary for using \@chapapp
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{One}
\kant

\chapter{Two}
\kant


\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Again}
\kant

\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]