# Fancyheader and Appendix

Tags: fancyhdr

I am having some trouble combining fancyhdr with my Appendix. There's two problems. The first is that the header doesn't show the correct information on the page just before the Appendix (the last page of the main text).

It should look something like this:

[image: correct header]

But what I get is:

[image: bad header]

The second is that the header in the Appendix shows:

[image: appendix header]

And I would like 'Chapter' to be 'Appendix'. I've tried the suggestions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151117/chapter-heading-appearing-in-appendix), but those don't seem to work. The relevant code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{Entanglement Entropy}
\fancyhead[C]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[R]{Section \thesection}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{title}
\input{chapters/chapter05}

\appendix
\chapter{another title}
\input{chapters/appendix}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your example so that it compiles. Remember also that we do not have your files!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that the switch to the appendices is affecting the header on the final page of the last chapter. To fix that, you can use `\clearpage` beforehand.

The second is that you have told TeX to use `Chapter \thechapter` for the central header and so it will keep doing so. One way to fix this is to tell it what you want it to do instead. I've just redefined the central header at the appropriate point which is probably the simplest solution.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{biblatex,kantlipsum}

\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{Entanglement Entropy}
\fancyhead[C]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[R]{Section \thesection}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

  \chapter{title}
  \kant[1-6]
  \clearpage

  \appendix
  \fancyhead[C]{Appendix \thechapter}
  \chapter{another title}
  \kant[7-10]

  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Last page before appendix]
[image: Appendix header]