# Chapter and Appendix in header mixed

Tags: fancyhdr, appendices

I'm trying to compile a document with multiple chapters and an appendix but run into problems with the `fancyhdr` package. After compilation, I do not get the desired effect of `\chaptername` appearing at the right place.

[image]
[image]

Page 5 marks the actual start of the `\chapter{Dummy test}`

[image]

---

A minimum working example that reproduces my issue is below [compiled with `xelatex`]:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\chaptername\ \thechapter}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage

\begin{appendices}
    \renewcommand\chaptername{Appendix}
    \chapter{Dummy test}
    \section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

I am aware of similar questions, such as [chapter-heading-appearing-in-appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151117/chapter-heading-appearing-in-appendix/151137) and [fancyheader-and-appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184996/fancyheader-and-appendix), but neither solves my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\chaptername\ \thechapter}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\appendix

\renewcommand\chaptername{Appendix}
\chapter{Dummy test}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]


\end{document}
```

[image]